# maintain scope with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I maintain scope with this?

**Original**

```
var Base = new function() {

    var canvas;
    var context;

    this.init = function()
    {
        console.log("Canvas: " + $("canvas")[0])

        this.canvas = $("canvas")[0];
        console.log("Context: " + this.canvas.getContext('2d'))
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        $(window).resize(handleWindowResize);

        handleWindowResize();
    };

    function handleWindowResize()
    {
        console.log("Resize Canvas [" + this.canvas + "] to {width: " +
            $(window).width() + "," + $(window).width() + "}");
        this.canvas.width = $(window).width();
        this.canvas.height = $(window).height(); 
    }
}

$(window).load(function() { new Base.init() });
```

---

**Ouput:**

```
Canvas: [object HTMLCanvasElement]
Context: [object CanvasRenderingContext2D]
Resize Canvas [undefined] to {width: 1680,1680}
Resize Canvas [undefined] to {width: 1680,1680}
```

**Revised**

```
var Base = function() {
  this.canvas;
  this.context;
}
Base.prototype = {
  init: function()
  {
    console.log("init :: " + this);

    this.canvas = $('canvas')[0];
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d')

    $(window).resize(this.handleWindowResize);
    this.handleWindowResize(null);
  },

  handleWindowResize: function()
  {
    console.log($(window) + " resized set canvas (" + this.canvas + ")" +
        " width,height = " + $(window).width() + "," + $(window).height());
  },

  toString: function()
  {
    return "[Base]";
  }
}

$(window).load(function() { var c = new Base(); c.init(); });
```

**Output: (init)**

```
init :: [Base]
[object Object] resized set canvas ([object HTMLCanvasElement]) width,height = 1659,630
```

**Output: (on window resize)**

```
[object Object] resized set canvas (undefined) width,height = 1658,630
```

Comment: where do you want to 'maintain scope'?

Comment: this.canvas = undefiend

should return [object HTMLCanvasElement] as that is what is set to in the init method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of the [Module pattern](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2007/07/24/show-love-to-the-module-pattern/) at work:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Base = function() {

            //Private Variables
            var canvas;
            var context;

            //Private Function
            function handleWindowResize()
            {
                console.log("Resize Canvas [" + canvas + "] to {width: " + $(window).width() + "," + $(window).width() + "}");
                canvas.width = $(window).width();
                canvas.height = $(window).height(); 
            }

            //Public Functions
            return {

                init: function()
                {
                    console.log("Canvas: " + $("canvas")[0])

                    canvas = $("canvas")[0];
                    console.log("Context: " + canvas.getContext('2d'))
                    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    $(window).resize(handleWindowResize);

                    handleWindowResize();
                }

            };

        }();

        $(window).load(function() { Base.init() });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <canvas></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery changes what object "this" refers to in its callback method.  What you should do is store a reference of your objects "this" reference at the beginning:

```
var Base = new function() {
var self = this;
var canvas;
var context;
```

And then where you want to refer to the base object use self.

Comment: I don't know who voted your suggestion down, but this is the only one that has actually worked so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use:
    handleWindowResize.call(this)
Instead Of:
    handleWindowResize()

This will change the scope.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're coming from another language and need to get a solid idea of how constructors work in JS.

You have `this.name=function(){}` for one function, and a function declaration for another. Is there a reason you're using `new function` for the Base object? Executing `new Base.init()` doesn't seem quite right, either. The constructor is creating a new object, but you're discarding it, and only using the constructor to execute imperative code?  You're not executing Base, so it could just be an object literal.

I really suggest checking out Doug Crockford's articles on inheritance and objects in JS. This SO Question talks about some other object creation techniques. Try searching for Crockford's The Good Parts. 
[What is happening in Crockford's object creation technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766057/what-is-happening-in-crockfords-object-creation-technique)

I discarded the canvas stuff since I haven't worked with canvas. This will execute without errors.

```
<html><head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
   var Base = {
      canvas:null,
      context:null,

      init:function()
         {
         console.log("Canvas: " + $("#canvas")[0]);

         this.canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
         console.log("Context: " + this.canvas)
         //this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
         this.handleWindowResize=function(){
         console.log("Resize Canvas [" + this.canvas + "] to {width: " + $(window).width() + "," +     $(window).width() + "}");
         this.canvas.style.width = $(window).width();
         this.canvas.style.height = $(window).height();
         }
        } 
      };


      $(window).load(function() { var c= new Base.init(); c.handleWindowResize()});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='canvas' style='width:400px;background-color:red;height:30px;'>a div called Canvas</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this does work and even being a hack matthew-manela's answer still provides me with the desired effect. I don't want to have a single bloated `    init()` method.

I can see where you are going and I like the principal I just don't know how to get it to work exactly. And it probably does resolve around improper constructor.

Comment: @cynicaljoy I think you're being too hard on yourself (context in JS is difficult), and the use of var self = this is commonplace, not hacky at all. Check out this post, which shows the pattern Cole is suggesting but without the all-encompassing init function: http://www.wait-till-i.com/2007/07/24/show-love-to-the-module-pattern/

Comment: Well now I am onto something like what Cole suggested but I can't get this.canvas to return inside of the `   handleWindowResize` method when being triggered by the event listener. If I use `    this.handleWindowResize()` then it works.

Comment: @cynicaljoy you can always edit your question and paste in more code if you need to. And yeah, using `var self=this` is common in JS, that is a good way to go. I still wouldn't work with `new function`, and the mixed style of function assignment, since it's confusing,  and I think the way you were doing 1/2 OO, 1/2 imperative makes as much sense as a large init function. Whatever works for you, of course!

Comment: @Cole I added a 'Revised' section to the Question, I would like to figure out how to use it this way rather than keep it as is because this is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several syntax errors. If `handleWindowResize` is a method within your Base object, then you should declare it similar to `this.init` and call it as `this.handleWindowResize`.

Comment: The codes doesn't have syntax errors. It may have poor formatting, but in either case when declaring such a statement a more _helpful_ thing would be to point out what that might be rather than just making a statement.

The mechanic doesn't tell you "There is something with with the car." when he gives you the keys back. At least not a good one.

Comment: No syntax errors. I think the intent was to create a private function. (Right?)

Comment: @cynicaljoy, your original post had syntax errors. I tried it on www.jsfiddle.net. I did make suggestions. Furthermore, the mere fact that I provided an answer shows my intention to be *helpful*. Unfortunately, it seems like this wasn't up to your standard.

Comment: my original post is still the one at the top, hasn't changed. The new revised one I just posted 15 minutes ago based off the suggestions of Cole. Here is the changes you suggested http://pastebin.com/Rq0v5LC8 - please put that into jsfiddle.net and try it. Because here is what I get when I test in Chrome 6, Safari 5, and Firefox 3.6.7 -> `    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'handleWindowResize'`