# Slice specific keys in javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

In rails, i have a special `slice` [method](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) to keep in `Hash` only keys I need. It is very handy to permit only required keys in a hash.

Is there a method like this in **Node.js**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Answer (score 23):

In JavaScript there is no such method, however, in libraries like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) there is the method called [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick)

```js
var data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
console.log(_.pick(data, 'a', 'c'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

you can install `lodash` via `npm`

```
npm install lodash --save
```

and then require it to your project

```
var _ = require('lodash') // import all methods
// or just import pick method
// var pick = require('lodash/object/pick');
```

Or you can implement your own pick with new ES features, like so

```js
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const pick = (obj, ...args) => ({
  ...args.reduce((res, key) => ({ ...res, [key]: obj[key] }), { })
})

console.log(
  pick(data, 'a', 'b')
)
```

Answer (score 17):

These are the coolest solutions.

Hard corded version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39333479/683157

```
const object = { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7  };
const picked = (({ a, c }) => ({ a, c }))(object);

console.log(picked); // { a: 5, c: 7 }
```

Generic version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184094/683157

```
const pick = (...props) => o => props.reduce((a, e) => ({ ...a, [e]: o[e] }), {});
pick('color', 'height')(elmo);
```

Comment: generic version works great with map. ```users.map(pick('id','name'))```

Comment: Why the `...props` in the signature instead of just `props`?

Comment: @srchulo if you use `props` instead of `...props` you should call with array like this: `pick(['color', 'height'])(elmo);`

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what @Brandon Belvin said, here is an ES6 equivalent:

```js
/**
 * A pure function to pick specific keys from object, similar to https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick
 * @param {Object}obj: The object to pick the specified keys from
 * @param {Array}keys: A list of all keys to pick from obj
 */
const pick = (obj, keys) => 
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(i => keys.includes(i))
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
      return acc;
    }, {})

// Test code
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
console.log(pick(data, ['a', 'c']));
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/addi90/b624e8ce732f88eb41c1f16df7d24562#file-pick-js) is the gist I have created for common functional utilities, including the definition of `pick()`, similar to https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with what's already built into JavaScript. Here's a quick method that's compatible with ES5 (and can be made slightly more concise in ES2015):

```
function slice(object, keys) {
    return Object.keys(object)
        .filter(function (key) {
            return keys.indexOf(key) >= 0;
        })
        .reduce(function (acc, key) {
            acc[key] = object[key];
            return acc;
        }, {});
}
```

This method purposefully does not mutate the object it's inspecting. So if you want to change the original object, just assign the output of `slice` to your original variable.

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
var y = slice(x, [ 'b', 'd' ]);

console.log(x);
// { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }

console.log(y);
// { b: 2, d: 4 }
```

This will work for simple applications where you only need to look at the first-level keys, but you can expand this to behave recursively, if necessary.

Comment: this looks better .... `keys.indexOf(key) >= 0;` -> `keys.includes(key)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you have three options available.

1. `delete` the properties you do not need, or
2. copy/clone the object and then `delete` the properties you don't need.
3. apply some filtering conditions while copying/cloning the object.

Without more info it's difficult to know the best approach to copying/cloning an object, but as you mentioned hash tables one might presume that you are talking about Object literals.  The follow code works, but whether it is the 'best' approach is perhaps something others will be willing to comment on (also see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766057/what-is-happening-in-crockfords-object-creation-technique)).

```
var hashTable = {
    d1: '1',
    d2: '2',
    d3: '3',
    d4: '4',
    d5: '5',
    d6: '6'
};
var filter = new RegExp("d1|d3|d5");

function cloneHashTable(table, conditions) {
    var obj = {};

    for (var h in table) {
        if (table.hasOwnProperty(h)) {
            if (h.match(conditions) !== null) obj[h] = table[h];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var hashClone = cloneHashTable(hashTable, filter);

console.debug(hashTable);
console.debug(hashClone);

//=> Object { d1: "1", d2: "2", d3: "3", d4: "4", d5: "5", d6: "6" }
//=> Object { d1: "1", d3: "3", d5: "5" }
```

Of course, this only works if you know what is in the table and you know what you want/need from it - and what you don't.

Hope this helped. :)