# How to filter an object according to specification given in another object?

Tags: javascript, filter, object-literal

I want to filter out data from an *object* according to specification given in another object.

For example, consider the following `BandAndAlbums` object that holds **raw** data about 3 bands (*Beatles*, *Aerosmith*, and *Queen*):

```js
const BandAndAlbums = {
  beatles: {
    origin: 'liverpool',
    genres: ['rock', 'pop', 'beat', 'psychedelia'],
    labels: ['parlophone', 'apple', 'capitol'],
    discography: {
      yellowSubmarine: {
        released: 1969,
        length: 39.16,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'apple',
      },
      rubberSoul: {
        released: 1965,
        length: 34.55,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'parlophone',
      },
      letItBe: {
        released: 1970,
        length: 35.1,
        producer: 'phil spector',
        label: 'apple',
      },
      revolver: {
        released: 1966,
        length: 35.01,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'parlophone',
      },
    },
  },
  aerosmith: {
    origin: 'boston',
    genres: [
      'hard rock',
      'blues rock',
      'rock and roll',
      'glam metal',
      'heavy metal',
    ],
    labels: ['columbia', 'geffen'],
    discography: {
      doneWithMirrors: {
        released: 1985,
        length: 35.42,
        producer: 'ted templeman',
        label: 'geffen',
      },
      rocks: {
        released: 1976,
        length: 34.31,
        producer: 'jack douglas',
        label: 'columbia',
      },
      nineLives: {
        released: 1997,
        length: 62.54,
        producer: 'kevin shirley',
        label: 'columbia',
      },
    },
  },
  queen: {
    origin: 'london',
    genres: ['rock'],
    labels: [
      'emi',
      'parlophone',
      'elektra',
      'capitol',
      'hollywood',
      'island',
      'virgin emi',
    ],
    discography: {
      aNightAtTheOpera: {
        released: 1975,
        length: 43.08,
        producer: 'roy thomas baker',
        label: 'emi',
      },
      newsOfTheWorld: {
        released: 1977,
        length: 39.1,
        producer: 'queen',
        label: 'emi',
      },
      aKindOfMagic: {
        released: 1986,
        length: 40.42,
        producer: 'queen',
        label: 'emi',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I want to filter `BandAndAlbums`, to end with only chosen albums per band, and just the `length` and `producer` properties in each.

If I specify the albums that I want in the following `requestedAlbums`:

```js
const requestedAlbums = {
  queen: ['aNightAtTheOpera', 'aKindOfMagic'],
  beatles: ['rubberSoul', 'letItBe', 'revolver'],
  aerosmith: ['doneWithMirrors', 'nineLives'],
};
```

how can I filter `BandAndAlbums` against it, and create a new object, with just `length` and `producer` per chosen album?

*desired output*

```js
const desiredOutput = {
  beatles: {
    rubberSoul: {
      length: 34.55,
      producer: 'george martin',
    },
    letItBe: {
      length: 35.1,
      producer: 'phil spector',
    },
    revolver: {
      length: 35.01,
      producer: 'george martin',
    },
  },
  aerosmith: {
    doneWithMirrors: {
      length: 35.42,
      producer: 'ted templeman',
    },
    nineLives: {
      length: 62.54,
      producer: 'kevin shirley',
    },
  },
  queen: {
    aNightAtTheOpera: {
      length: 43.08,
      producer: 'roy thomas baker',
    },
    aKindOfMagic: {
      length: 40.42,
      producer: 'queen',
    },
  },
};
```

---

EDIT

---

To address the comments below, I shall add that I am familiar with the procedure of converting an object into an array (with `Object.entries()`) thus promoting the usage of array methods (e.g., `.filter()`, `.map()`, etc.), and finally converting back to an object with `Object.fromEntries()`.

Unfortunately, in this case I'm a bit lost with how to do what I need. I assume that in order to jumpstart, I need to do something along the lines of:

```js
Object.entries(BandAndAlbums).map( ([k, v]) => [k, v.discography])
```

(But then I get this `undefined`)

```js
// [ [ 'queen', undefined ],
//   [ 'beatles', undefined ],
//   [ 'aerosmith', undefined ] ]
```

So I'll be grateful is someone could steer me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: No attempt at all?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I am familiar with array methods and object methods. However, the piece I'm missing here is how to *programmatically* do the filtering based on `requestedAlbums`. I'll clarify that in my question.

Comment: @trincot, I'm not sure how to even approach this...

Comment: What have you already tried? Your question should include your own best attempt at solving your own problem.

Comment: @Emman _“how to programmatically do the filtering”_ — As opposed to what? The Array and Object methods are the programmatic way to do this. _“I'm not sure how to even approach this”_ — Then, as always, start with breaking down the problem into smaller steps. Surely, you can come up with _some_ code that covers these smaller steps.

Comment: The thing about storing lists in object form instead of array form is that now, to do useful manipulation, you will be converting the object to the array form, do the operation, and then convert it back to object form.  There’s nothing inherently wrong with your data format, it’s just harder to do things like filtering etc.  See [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: `Object.entries(BandAndAlbums).map(([ k, v ]) => [ k, v.discography ])` works fine. The second array elements are not `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with the combination of `Array.reduce()` and `Array.entries()`:

```js
const BandAndAlbums = {
    beatles: {
        origin: 'liverpool',
        genres: ['rock', 'pop', 'beat', 'psychedelia'],
        labels: ['parlophone', 'apple', 'capitol'],
        discography: {
        yellowSubmarine: {
            released: 1969,
            length: 39.16,
            producer: 'george martin',
            label: 'apple',
        },
        rubberSoul: {
            released: 1965,
            length: 34.55,
            producer: 'george martin',
            label: 'parlophone',
        },
        letItBe: {
            released: 1970,
            length: 35.1,
            producer: 'phil spector',
            label: 'apple',
        },
        revolver: {
            released: 1966,
            length: 35.01,
            producer: 'george martin',
            label: 'parlophone',
        },
        },
    },
    aerosmith: {
        origin: 'boston',
        genres: [
        'hard rock',
        'blues rock',
        'rock and roll',
        'glam metal',
        'heavy metal',
        ],
        labels: ['columbia', 'geffen'],
        discography: {
        doneWithMirrors: {
            released: 1985,
            length: 35.42,
            producer: 'ted templeman',
            label: 'geffen',
        },
        rocks: {
            released: 1976,
            length: 34.31,
            producer: 'jack douglas',
            label: 'columbia',
        },
        nineLives: {
            released: 1997,
            length: 62.54,
            producer: 'kevin shirley',
            label: 'columbia',
        },
        },
    },
    queen: {
        origin: 'london',
        genres: ['rock'],
        labels: [
        'emi',
        'parlophone',
        'elektra',
        'capitol',
        'hollywood',
        'island',
        'virgin emi',
        ],
        discography: {
        aNightAtTheOpera: {
            released: 1975,
            length: 43.08,
            producer: 'roy thomas baker',
            label: 'emi',
        },
        newsOfTheWorld: {
            released: 1977,
            length: 39.1,
            producer: 'queen',
            label: 'emi',
        },
        aKindOfMagic: {
            released: 1986,
            length: 40.42,
            producer: 'queen',
            label: 'emi',
        },
        },
    },
};

const requestedAlbums = {
    queen: ['aNightAtTheOpera', 'aKindOfMagic'],
    beatles: ['rubberSoul', 'letItBe', 'revolver'],
    aerosmith: ['doneWithMirrors', 'nineLives'],
};

const result2 = Object.entries(requestedAlbums).reduce((tot, [k, v]) => {
    // all songs of the band
    const allSongs = BandAndAlbums[k].discography

    // take chosen ones
    const chosenSongs = v.reduce((chosen, song) => {
        chosen[song] = {
            length: allSongs[song].length,
            producer: allSongs[song].producer
        }
        return chosen
    }, {})

    // add to total
    tot[k] = chosenSongs

    return tot
}, {})

console.log(result2)
```

Comment: Many thanks! Please note that your `result` returns the bands with all album properties, whereas I want just the `length` and `producer` properties (see `desiredOutput` from my question). I was trying to utilize [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53202834/6105259) before returning `chosen` in the `chosenSongs()` function, but it doesn't work :-/ do you have an idea?

Comment: @Emman Here you go. Now it gives only the `length` and `producer`. Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if this solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

I think below function will solve your requirement:

```js
const BandAndAlbums = {
  beatles: {
    origin: 'liverpool',
    genres: ['rock', 'pop', 'beat', 'psychedelia'],
    labels: ['parlophone', 'apple', 'capitol'],
    discography: {
      yellowSubmarine: {
        released: 1969,
        length: 39.16,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'apple',
      },
      rubberSoul: {
        released: 1965,
        length: 34.55,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'parlophone',
      },
      letItBe: {
        released: 1970,
        length: 35.1,
        producer: 'phil spector',
        label: 'apple',
      },
      revolver: {
        released: 1966,
        length: 35.01,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'parlophone',
      },
    },
  },
  aerosmith: {
    origin: 'boston',
    genres: [
      'hard rock',
      'blues rock',
      'rock and roll',
      'glam metal',
      'heavy metal',
    ],
    labels: ['columbia', 'geffen'],
    discography: {
      doneWithMirrors: {
        released: 1985,
        length: 35.42,
        producer: 'ted templeman',
        label: 'geffen',
      },
      rocks: {
        released: 1976,
        length: 34.31,
        producer: 'jack douglas',
        label: 'columbia',
      },
      nineLives: {
        released: 1997,
        length: 62.54,
        producer: 'kevin shirley',
        label: 'columbia',
      },
    },
  },
  queen: {
    origin: 'london',
    genres: ['rock'],
    labels: [
      'emi',
      'parlophone',
      'elektra',
      'capitol',
      'hollywood',
      'island',
      'virgin emi',
    ],
    discography: {
      aNightAtTheOpera: {
        released: 1975,
        length: 43.08,
        producer: 'roy thomas baker',
        label: 'emi',
      },
      newsOfTheWorld: {
        released: 1977,
        length: 39.1,
        producer: 'queen',
        label: 'emi',
      },
      aKindOfMagic: {
        released: 1986,
        length: 40.42,
        producer: 'queen',
        label: 'emi',
      },
    },
  },
};



const requestedAlbums = {
  queen: ['aNightAtTheOpera', 'aKindOfMagic'],
  beatles: ['rubberSoul', 'letItBe', 'revolver'],
  aerosmith: ['doneWithMirrors', 'nineLives'],
};


// This is your desired funciton
var filterAlbum=(a,r)=>{
    var ou = {};
    for(let ri in r){
        if(typeof a[ri]!== 'undefined'){
            var our = {};
            for(let di of r[ri]){
               if(typeof a[ri].discography[di]!=='undefined'){
                    let dis = a[ri].discography[di];
                    our[di]={length:dis.length,producer:dis.producer};
                }
            }
            ou[ri] = our;
        }
    }
    return ou;
}


const desiredOutput = filterAlbum(BandAndAlbums,requestedAlbums);

console.log(desiredOutput);
```

You can ask more if you need more filters here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` to get an array of pairs, then do all the mapping and filtering, and finally turn the resulting array of pairs back to the result object with `Object.fromEntries`.

`Object.fromEntries` can also be applied at a nested level to produce the nested objects:

```js
const BandAndAlbums = {beatles: {origin: 'liverpool',genres: ['rock', 'pop', 'beat', 'psychedelia'],labels: ['parlophone', 'apple', 'capitol'],discography: {yellowSubmarine: {released: 1969,length: 39.16,producer: 'george martin',label: 'apple',},rubberSoul: {released: 1965,length: 34.55,producer: 'george martin',label: 'parlophone',},letItBe: {released: 1970,length: 35.1,producer: 'phil spector',label: 'apple',},revolver: {released: 1966,length: 35.01,producer: 'george martin',label: 'parlophone',},},},aerosmith: {origin: 'boston',genres: ['hard rock','blues rock','rock and roll','glam metal','heavy metal',],labels: ['columbia', 'geffen'],discography: {doneWithMirrors: {released: 1985,length: 35.42,producer: 'ted templeman',label: 'geffen',},rocks: {released: 1976,length: 34.31,producer: 'jack douglas',label: 'columbia',},nineLives: {released: 1997,length: 62.54,producer: 'kevin shirley',label: 'columbia',},},},queen: {origin: 'london',genres: ['rock'],labels: ['emi','parlophone','elektra','capitol','hollywood','island','virgin emi',],discography: {aNightAtTheOpera: {released: 1975,length: 43.08,producer: 'roy thomas baker',label: 'emi',},newsOfTheWorld: {released: 1977,length: 39.1,producer: 'queen',label: 'emi',},aKindOfMagic: {released: 1986,length: 40.42,producer: 'queen',label: 'emi',},},},};

const requestedAlbums = {queen: ['aNightAtTheOpera', 'aKindOfMagic'],beatles: ['rubberSoul', 'letItBe', 'revolver'],aerosmith: ['doneWithMirrors', 'nineLives'],};

const output = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(requestedAlbums).map(([band, albums]) => [
        band, 
        Object.fromEntries(
            albums.map(album => [album, BandAndAlbums[band].discography[album]])
                  .map(([album, {length, producer}]) => [album, {length, producer}])
        )
    ])
);
        
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a neat answer. However, I'm trying to understand how I could retain the name of the album in the `output`. All I could think of, right now, is to concatenate `band+albums`  when mapping over  `Object.entries(requestedAlbums)`. But it's a bit far from how I pictured the `desiredOutput` (see in my question).

Comment: I yes, I see. I have updated my answer to include the album keys.

Answer (score 1):

This could work, utilizing Object & Array functions.

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const filter = (BandAndAlbums, requestedAlbums) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(requestedAlbums).map(([name, list]) => [name, Object.fromEntries(
        list.map(entry => [entry, BandAndAlbums[name]?.discography[entry]])
      .filter(([entry, discography]) => discography)
      .map(([entry, {length, producer}]) => [entry, {length, producer}]
    ))]
  )
);

const BandAndAlbums = {
  beatles: {
    origin: 'liverpool',
    genres: ['rock', 'pop', 'beat', 'psychedelia'],
    labels: ['parlophone', 'apple', 'capitol'],
    discography: {
      yellowSubmarine: {
        released: 1969,
        length: 39.16,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'apple',
      },
      rubberSoul: {
        released: 1965,
        length: 34.55,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'parlophone',
      },
      letItBe: {
        released: 1970,
        length: 35.1,
        producer: 'phil spector',
        label: 'apple',
      },
      revolver: {
        released: 1966,
        length: 35.01,
        producer: 'george martin',
        label: 'parlophone',
      },
    },
  },
  aerosmith: {
    origin: 'boston',
    genres: [
      'hard rock',
      'blues rock',
      'rock and roll',
      'glam metal',
      'heavy metal',
    ],
    labels: ['columbia', 'geffen'],
    discography: {
      doneWithMirrors: {
        released: 1985,
        length: 35.42,
        producer: 'ted templeman',
        label: 'geffen',
      },
      rocks: {
        released: 1976,
        length: 34.31,
        producer: 'jack douglas',
        label: 'columbia',
      },
      nineLives: {
        released: 1997,
        length: 62.54,
        producer: 'kevin shirley',
        label: 'columbia',
      },
    },
  },
  queen: {
    origin: 'london',
    genres: ['rock'],
    labels: [
      'emi',
      'parlophone',
      'elektra',
      'capitol',
      'hollywood',
      'island',
      'virgin emi',
    ],
    discography: {
      aNightAtTheOpera: {
        released: 1975,
        length: 43.08,
        producer: 'roy thomas baker',
        label: 'emi',
      },
      newsOfTheWorld: {
        released: 1977,
        length: 39.1,
        producer: 'queen',
        label: 'emi',
      },
      aKindOfMagic: {
        released: 1986,
        length: 40.42,
        producer: 'queen',
        label: 'emi',
      },
    },
  },
};

const requestedAlbums = {
  queen: ['aNightAtTheOpera', 'aKindOfMagic'],
  beatles: ['rubberSoul', 'letItBe', 'revolver'],
  aerosmith: ['doneWithMirrors', 'nineLives'],
};

console.log(filter(BandAndAlbums, requestedAlbums));
```